# Bigquery similar query different output

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 standard SQL queries in Bigquery. They are:

Query1:

```
select sfcase.case_id
, sfuser.user_id
, sfcase_create_date
, sfcase_status
, sfcase_origin
, sfcategory_category1
, sfcategory_category2
, sfcase_priority
, sftime_elapsedmin
, sftime_targetmin
, sfcase_sla_closemin
, if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=0,"0"
,if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=1,"1"
,if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=2,"2"
,"3"))) as comment_response
from(
  select id as case_id
  , timestamp_add(createddate, interval 7 hour) as sfcase_create_date
  , status as sfcase_status
  , origin as sfcase_origin
  , priority as sfcase_priority
  , case when status = 'Closed' then timestamp_diff(timestamp_add(closeddate, interval 7 hour),timestamp_add(createddate, interval 7 hour),minute)
      end as sfcase_sla_closemin
  , case_category__c
  from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case` 
) sfcase

left join(
  select upper(x1st_category__c) as sfcategory_category1
  , upper(x2nd_category__c) as sfcategory_category2
  , id
  from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_category` 
) sfcategory
on sfcategory.id = sfcase.case_category__c

left join(
  select parentid as parentid
  from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_comment` 
) sfcomment
on sfcase.case_id = sfcomment.parentid

left join(
  select ELAPSEDTIMEINMINS as sftime_elapsedmin
  , TARGETRESPONSEINMINS as sftime_targetmin
  , caseid
  from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_milestone` 
)sftime
on sfcase.case_id = sftime.caseid

left join(
  select id as user_id 
  , createddate
  from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_user` 
)sfuser
on date(sfuser.createddate) = date(sfcase.sfcase_create_date)
group by 1
, 2
, 3
, 4
, 5
, 6
, 7 
, 8 
, 9 
, 10
, 11
```

Query2:

```
select sfcase.id as case_id
, sfuser.id as user_id
, timestamp_add(sfcase.createddate, interval 7 hour) as sf_create_date
, sfcase.status as sf_status
, sfcase.origin as sf_origin
, upper(sfcategory.x1st_category__c) as sf_category1
, sfcategory.x2nd_category__c as sf_category2
, sfcase.priority as sf_priority
, sftime.ELAPSEDTIMEINMINS as sf_elapsedresponsemin
, sftime.TARGETRESPONSEINMINS as sf_targetresponsemin
, case when sfcase.status = 'Closed' then timestamp_diff(timestamp_add(sfcase.closeddate, interval 7 hour),timestamp_add(sfcase.createddate, interval 7 hour),minute)
    end as sla_closemin
, if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=0,"0"
,if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=1,"1"
,if(count(sfcomment.parentid)=2,"2"
,"3"))) as comment_response

from `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case` as sfcase
left join `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_category` as sfcategory
  on sfcategory.id = sfcase.case_category__c
left join `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_comment`  as sfcomment
  on sfcase.id = sfcomment.parentid
left join `some_of_my_dataset.cs_case_milestone` as sftime
  on sfcase.id = sftime.caseid
left join `some_of_my_dataset.cs_user` as sfuser
  on date(sfuser.createddate) = date(sfcase.createddate)
group by 1
, 2
, 3
, 4
, 5
, 6
, 7 
, 8 
, 9 
, 10
, 11
```

I tried to run them in the same time. Query1 perform faster with less rows of data, while Query2 perform longer with more rows of data. Both of Query1 and Query2 have 12 columns.

Why do they return different result?
Which query should i use?

update: rename my dataset

Comment: Can you please try to reduce the amount of columns and joins as much as possible without removing your problem? less complex queries are easier to analyze.

Comment: Hi there, I am with Google Cloud Platform Support, I agree with @MartinWeitzmann that your queries are too complicated to troubleshoot here. I would suggest that you open instead an issue in the Private Issue Tracker, marked as Private. Here's the component you should use: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491370. This way, you can share some Job IDs which will allow us to see more details about your queries and resolve this.